# Name attribute is coming up Nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a destination, but it keeps telling me in my browser that 'name' is nil when it redirects redirects to my 'show' view.

Error I receive

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Here are my controller actions for new, create, and show:

```
def show
        @destination = Destination.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end

def new
        @destination = Destination.new
    end

    def create
        @destination = Destination.create(dest_params)
        redirect_to user_destination_path(current_user, @destination.id )
        
    end

    private

    def dest_params
        params.require(:destination).permit(:name,:user_id)
    end
```

My new form where I enter the name of the destination:

```
<h2>Add a destination</h2>

<div>
<%= form_for @destination do |f|%>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

here is my read/show view:

```
<h3>Added destination</h3>
<div>
    <p><%= @destination.name %></p>
</div>
```

Before all this I was getting missing required keys [:id] errors, but I seemed to fix that but for some reason I suspect that might have something to do with the issue I am having now. Let me know if you are able to spot the issue

Updated Error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"destinations", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting?  Is it that you are calling the method `name` on a nil object?

Comment: @RockwellRice I updated it for you.  It shouldn't be a nil object, but  it might be.

Comment: In your redirect, you are passing the symbol ``:id`` as the second parameter rather than the actual record ID, so your ``.find_by`` in ``.show`` returns ``nil``. Should be ``user_destination_path(current_user, @destination.id)``

Comment: @rmlockerd, I made that adjustment and it gave me another error. I'll post it up top for your review.

Comment: @rmlockerd this is the issue I was having before the one I first posted. The destination id attribute is not setting somehow.

Comment: Is a ``Destination`` record actually being created in the database? The ``.create`` method always returns an object, even if it does not save successfully. Change that to ``.create!`` -- which throws an error if the save fails -- and you should see the real problem. Likely a validation error.

Comment: @rmlockerd You are right sir it is a validation issue!  Its telling me User must exist.

Comment: @rmlockerd I forgot to mention that this is a nested route if that helps.

Comment: Please, read the error message again. The error message is not saying what you claim it says. The error message does *not* say that `name` is `nil`. It says that `nil` has no `name` method, in other words, the object that you are *calling `name` on* is `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is a total lack of error handling. You're not checking at all if the user provided valid input or if the record was even saved in your create method.

```
def create
  @destination = Destination.create(dest_params)
  redirect_to user_destination_path(current_user, @destination.id )
end
```

If the record is not saved  for example due to a failed validation `@destination.id` is nil.

In your `show` method you're using `find_by` instead of `find` which just lets the error slide instead of raising a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

Your controller should actually look like:

```
class DestinationsController
  def show
    # will raise if the record is not found and return a 404 not found response 
    # instead of just exploding
    @destination = Destination.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def new
    @destination = Destination.new
  end

  def create
    # never just assume that the record is created unless you want 
    # to get kicked in the pants.
    @destination = Destination.new(dest_params)
    if @destination.save
      # this route really does not need to be nested.
      # see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting
      redirect_to user_destination_path(current_user, @destination)
    else
      # re-render the form with errors
      render :new 
    end
  end
  
  private

  def dest_params
    params.require(:destination).permit(:name,:user_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Almost worked but its still giving me the validation issue. I do definitely see your point.

Comment: I can't really tell you what is wrong based on such a vague description. You need tests to actually automatically test that a record is created with valid attributes and not created with invalid attributes. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

Comment: For the time being I made the validation optional in my Destination for belongs_to :user association until I get a better handle on this. It's now doing what it needs to do, but not sure how this goes in regards to best practice.

Comment: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

Comment: If you want the destination to be created by the current user you would setup a `has_many :destinations` association in your User model and then change the first line of the create method to `@destination = current_user.destinations.new(dest_params)`. That will assign the `user_id` attribute - and is not open to simple parameter tampering like if you passed it through a form.

Comment: I did  setup the has_many relationship in my user model. I will try modifying my create method as well.